# SQL condense / combine rows

Tags: sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
      FFDCUSN, 
      FFDCA1B, 
      BSLINK, 
      S4IDNAM, 
      S4IDTYP
FROM S2151BDW.PWRDTA.FFDCSTBP T0
     LEFT JOIN 
     S2151BDW.PWRDTA.BSLINKP T1 ON T1.BSCUSN = T0.FFDCUSN
     LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     S2151BDW.PWRDTA.S4IDISTP T2 ON T2.S4ICUSN = T1.BSCUSN
WHERE FFDCMPN = '  1' 
      AND FFDCUSN = '    100016'
ORDER BY FFDCUSN
```

FFDCSTBP and BSLINKP each do have 2 rows linked to the main table however my results bring back 4 rows, can they be condensed into 2? I have been trying many suggestions I have found here and on other sites without any luck. Is this possible? If so, how can I do it?

[These are the results I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYLuv.png)

Comment: It's good programming practice to qualify all columns when several tables are involved, especially when you're doing outer joins. (Just like `T1.BSCUSN` instead of just `FFDCUSN`.)

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` are the same. Stick to one of them to write clearer code.

Comment: T0, T1 and T2 are poor table aliases. Chose something that makes sense, like `F` for `FFDCSTBP` etc.

Comment: Sample data (In the form of create table and insert statements for easy copy and pasting into a test database) and expected results would be nice. And maybe human-readable table and column names?

Comment: You're getting 4 distinct rows based on the screenshot you shared so the result is correct for that query. Some sample data and expected result would be helpful here.

Comment: The naming of the columns and tables or very difficult to read. Additionally, having the create and insert statements would help  a lot.

Comment: In your query, FFDCSTBP is the main table, I don't understand your comment. As @Meckel'sDiverticulum said, the result is correct according to the select

Comment: Thank you all for responding, I appreciate your comments, I am always trying to improve. Table T01 has two different values in the BSLINK field and table T2 has two values in the S4IDNAM and S4IDTYP fields. I would like a query that would return just two rows.